# Java sessionCreate doesn't work

Tags: java

I am using Java EE. I have some problems with session. I have created Listener class and it looks like this:

```
package RandomPackage;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

/**
 * Application Lifecycle Listener implementation class Listener
 *
 */
@WebListener
public class Listener implements HttpSessionListener {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public Listener() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)
 */
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0)  { 
    System.out.print("Session Created");
   arg0.getSession().setAttribute("Name", "Geoge");
}

/**
 * @see HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent)
 */
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0)  { 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Now in my HTML file I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Hello </h1>
 <form action="SessionTest" method="POST">
    <input type="submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my SessionTest servlet looks like this:

```
package RandomPackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/SessionTest")
public class SessionTest extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public SessionTest() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("String is " + (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("Name"));
}

}
```

It should have the output: "String is George" but instead it never prints "Session Created" and the output is "String is null"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the same code it is working for me  see the output[image]

Comment: I can't figure out the reason really.

Comment: Which server are you using